# General solution of $\ddot{y} + 4\omega^2y = 2\omega gt\sin{\lambda} \equiv ct$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

In solving a problem involving differential equations, I come across the following:

> $$\ddot{y} + 4\omega^2y = 2\omega gt\sin{\lambda} \equiv ct$$
>
> The general solution is the general solution of the homogeneous equation and one particular solution of the inhomogeneous equation, i.e.,
>
> $$y = \frac{c}{4\omega^2}t + A\sin{2\omega t} + B\cos{2\omega t}$$

I'm at a loss as to how it got to $y$. I can only think of the following:

$$\dot y + 4\omega^2yt = \omega gt^2\sin{\lambda} + C$$

which of course is nowhere near what I read. I'd appreciate if someone can point me in the right direction.

Comment: I think it is fair to say that the particular solution $ct/(4\omega^2)$ is obvious, at least after one sees it.  Differentiating  twice will kill it, so $4\omega^2y=ct$ works.

Comment: @Andre, I'm not sure if I get what you said. If you could explain it better, I'd appreciate it. Where is $\ddot y$ in $4\omega^2 y = ct$, as you mentioned?

Comment: I assume the way you got to the last display was by attempting to antidifferentiate both sides of the first display, but when you antidifferentiated $y$ and got $yt$, well, that would be correct if $y$ were a constant, but it isn't. This may not help point you in the right direction, but it may also be useful to you to see what's wrong with the direction you took.

Comment: @Gerry, it's quite clear that $y$ is a function of $t$, so $\int y(t)dt = yt$, but it isn't anywhere near the given solution. So, how should I proceed?

Comment: @Kit: Without any offense intended, just trying to give useful advice: If you believe that $\int y(t)dt = yt$, I think you need to brush up your calculus skills before you have a go at solving inhomogeneous second-order differential equations. That only works if $y$ is a constant independent of $t$.

Comment: Please do not (for this part) even *think* in terms of integrating.  Let $y=\frac{c}{4\omega^2} t$. Does this $y$ satisfy the DE? Let's check by *substituting*. For *this* $y$, calculate $\ddot{y}$. What do you get? I get $0$. Calculate $4\omega^2y$. What do you get? I get $ct$. Calculate $\ddot{y}+4\omega^2y$. What do you get? I get $ct$. Let's now look at the right-hand side.  It *is* $ct$.  So the function $y$ we have been working with *is* a solution of the DE.

Comment: @joriki, thank you, I take your advice well :) I was also rather shaky with $\int y(t)dt = yt$. It was my hope with this question that any offered solution might help me recover that missing link in my calculus skills. Actually I grazed over the quoted statements and was able to follow the consequent parts of the solution. So, if you don't mind helping with what you have, don't worry, I think I can grok it somehow. It's been ~3 years since undergrad :)

Comment: @Kit: anon has already provided a solution. You can also check out [the Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_differential_equation#Nonhomogeneous_equation_with_constant_coefficients) to understand the theory, though the very general treatment there might be a bit of an overkill for this case; [here](http://www.efunda.com/math/ode/linearode_consthomo.cfm)'s a more specific treatment of the second-order homogeneous case. The general solution of the inhomogeneous equation is the sum of any solution of the inhomogeneous equation and all solutions of the homogeneous equation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When they write $\omega gt \sin \lambda\equiv ct$ they mean to quickly introduce the substitution $c:=\omega g \sin\lambda$. Note furthermore that differentiating any polynomial twice will reduce its degree by two, so twice differentiating a linear map will send it to $0$ (i.e. annihilate, or kill, it). Hence if we introduce for our particular solution a linear map (as the RHS is just a linear map), we can simply choose $y=ct / (4\omega^2)$. This way

$$(0)+4\omega^2\left(\frac{ct}{4\omega^2}\right)=ct.$$

The homogeneous part to the solution will solve $\ddot{y}+4\omega^2y=0$. The characteristic equation has solutions $r=\pm 2\omega i$, so the general solution will be of the form

$$\frac{ct}{4\omega^2}+\alpha e^{2\omega i}+\beta e^{-2\omega i}$$

or, after a change of variables,

$$\frac{ct}{4\omega^2}+A\sin2\omega t+B\cos2\omega t.$$

Edit: Apparently your scratchwork indicates you believed one could simply integrate $y$ to get $yt+C$. I  sternly agree with joriki's comment: this is false and it's going to be difficult to work with differential equations if you don't have the more elementary calculus fully understood yet.

Comment: Thank you, @anon. I had a hunch that I needed to use some characteristic polynomial, but I didn't know how to articulate it in my question, or simply forgot about the technique, really :)